# Type-qualifiers on function return type

Tags: c

Given the following C source code:

```
const int foo(void)
{
    return 42;
}
```

`gcc` compiles without errors, but with `-Wextra` or `-Wignored-qualifiers`, the following warning appears:

```
warning: type qualifiers ignored on function return type
```

I understand that there's good reason in C++ to distinguish between `const` functions and non-`const` functions, e.g. in the context of operator overloading.

In plain C however, I fail to see why `gcc` doesn't emit an error, or more concisely, why the standard allows `const` functions.

Why is it allowed to use type qualifiers on function return types?

Comment: See also http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12052468/type-qualifiers-on-function-return-type - though that's a C++ question it's concerning the same issue and the answer is the same.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Consider:

```
#include <stdio.h>

const char* f()
{
    return "hello";
}
int main()
{
    const char* c = f();

    *(c + 1) = 'a';

    return 0;
}
```

If `const` were not permitted on the return value then the [code](http://ideone.com/5jRbd) would compile (and cause undefined behaviour at runtime).

`const` is useful when a function returns a pointer to something unmodifiable.

Comment: Ah! Haven't thought of this case, since I avoid this technique anyway.

Comment: In this case, the function returns a unqualified pointer, not a const qualified object.

Answer (score 2):

Because it makes sense for pointer types, my guess is that it simply keeps the grammar simpler, so nobody thinks it's worth making `const` non-pointer return values be an error.

Also, your comparison with C++ is a bit off, since a constant method in C++ is declared by having `const` last:

```
int foo() const;
```

There is no relationship between a method being `const`, and a method having a `const` return value, they are completely distinct things. The syntax makes this fairly clear.

Comment: Your guess on the grammar's simplicity is a good point and probably the reason why it is allowed on non-pointer-types.

Answer (score 1):

It's irrelevant if the **value** returned from the function is qualified as `const`.

You cannot change the value returned even if it wasn't qualified.

```
foo() = -42; /* impossible to change the returned value */
```

So using `const` is redundant (and normally omitted).