# warning: type qualifiers ignored on function return type in gcc 4.1.2

Tags: c, linux, gcc

I am using gcc 4.1.2 on Linux, and I encountered the following warning:

```
warning: type qualifiers ignored on function return type
```

I tried to use "-Wno-ignored-qualifiers" to get rid of this warning but it seems not supported:

```
cc1: error: unrecognized command line option "-Wno-ignored-qualifiers"
```

Is there a way to disable such warnings in gcc 4.1.2?

Thanks a lot.

Comment: what code/line is causing this warning ?

Comment: functions return "const char *"

Comment: [first google search result for the warning](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1134237/pedantic-gcc-warning-type-qualifiers-on-function-return-type) (not away from here...)

Comment: @user1783732: If it's returning a `const char *` then it shouldn't cause this warning as that qualifier is meaningful and NOT ignored.  You must have something else.  Why don't you show the actual code that causes the warning?  It may be that you actually have a `char * const` when you really meant `const char *`, but you got confused by macros or typedefs, and that's what the warning is warning you about

Answer (score 2, accepted):

found the solution.  Use:

```
-Wno-return-type
```

Comment: i don't think it's a good idea to just disable warning, one should rather compile the code with a high warn level `-Wall`. BTW you could accept you own answer in order to mark the question as resolved.

Comment: Its indeed a horrible idea to disable a warning and consider the issue "fixed", unless you have a *very* strong knowledge of why you turned it off, and that is a legitimate thing to do in your code.  This is quite rare in practice.

Comment: the problem is that I cannot modify the source code. I have to find a solution without modifying the source code.

Answer (score 2):

As [seen here](https://stackoverflow.com/q/12052468/6309), a `const char *` would *not* trigger that warning.

A `const char` would, and the proper way to avoid that warning is, if possible, to change the return type from `const char` to `char`.

See as an example [commit ee5462d](https://github.com/git/git/commit/ee5462d6e71aad04628ccb8f078784468bfa4139) (27 Dec 2017) by [Junio C Hamano (`gitster`)](https://github.com/gitster) for Git 2.16 (Q1 2018).

> ### `sequencer.c`: drop '`const`' from function return type
>
> With `-Werror=ignored-qualifiers`, a function that claims to return
>   "`const char`" gets this error:
>
> ```
>    CC sequencer.o
> sequencer.c:798:19: error: type qualifiers ignored on function return
> type [-Werror=ignored-qualifiers]
>  static const char command_to_char(const enum todo_command command)
>                    ^
> ```